# Move fontAwesome 6 icon to the right

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, font-awesome-6

I am trying to move this icon to the top right of the file, but I can't, does anyone know how? (I got this icon for free from [fontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/))

Here's the code

```css
i {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d1950e8188.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i>
</head>
```

Comment: and icon inside the head element would be invalid. The head element is only for specific tags such as `script`, `link`, `meta`, `title` ... The icon belongs into the body element and can then be aligned with text-align of the wrapping element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `fa-solid` has `display: inline-block` by default (from this rule: `display: var(--fa-display,inline-block)` the `text-align:right` by itself won't work.

Here are a few solutions:

---

#### You can set the CSS vars `--fa-display` there is built in in font-awesome CSS and add `text-align: right`

```css
.fa-solid.fa-cart-shopping {
  --fa-display: block;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d1950e8188.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i>
```

#### If you like flex, you can use `display: flex; justify-content: flex-end;`

```css
.fa-solid.fa-cart-shopping {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d1950e8188.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the `text-align` to the wrapping element:

```css
#icon-wrapper {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d1950e8188.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="icon-wrapper">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i>
  </div>
</body>
```